Description of meaning of Phoible record properties
Phoible is a repository of cross-linguistic phonological inventory data, and it has data like this (JS object):
{
  InventoryID: '2325',
  Glottocode: 'ligu1248',
  ISO6393: 'lij',
  LanguageName: 'Ligurian',
  SpecificDialect: 'Ligurian (Miogliola)',
  GlyphID: '0079',
  Phoneme: 'y',
  Allophones: 'NA',
  Marginal: 'FALSE',
  SegmentClass: 'vowel',
  Source: 'ea',
  tone: '0',
  stress: '-',
  syllabic: '+',
  short: '-',
  long: '-',
  consonantal: '-',
  sonorant: '+',
  continuant: '+',
  delayedRelease: '0',
  approximant: '+',
  tap: '-',
  trill: '-',
  nasal: '-',
  lateral: '-',
  labial: '+',
  round: '+',
  labiodental: '-',
  coronal: '-',
  anterior: '0',
  distributed: '0',
  strident: '0',
  dorsal: '+',
  high: '+',
  low: '-',
  front: '+',
  back: '-',
  tense: '+',
  retractedTongueRoot: '-',
  advancedTongueRoot: '-',
  periodicGlottalSource: '+',
  epilaryngealSource: '-',
  spreadGlottis: '-',
  constrictedGlottis: '-',
  fortis: '0',
  lenis: '0',
  raisedLarynxEjective: '-',
  loweredLarynxImplosive: '-',
  click: '0'
}

At first I thought - means "No", and a + means "Yes" (boolean values), but landing on this CLDF structure dataset metadata, it looks like every prop has a range of possible values, not just booleans. For example, here are the values for spreadGlottis:
{
  "name": "spreadGlottis",
  "datatype": {
    "base": "string",
    "format": "+,-,-|+,-|0|+,0,-|-,-,+|+,0,-,-|N|+,-,+|-|-,+|+"
  }
}

Not really sure how to interpret this, or what each value means.
Where is the guide for this?
Pasting this entire question into ChatGPT led to https://phoible.org/conventions but it's not there. I have scoured dozens of pages. The metadata JSON file says conformsTo http://cldf.clld.org/v1.0/terms.rdf#StructureDataset but that is an insecure RDF file and I'm not sure how to read it.
Any ideas where I can find this information on what the values mean?

Actually, opening the terms.rdf file in a text editor, it doesn't even have the properties in it, so not very useful either. Downloading cldf/cldf: CLDF 1.3 .zip file doesn't help either. And https://github.com/search?q=spreadGlottis doesn't return anything either.

The double-escape sequences make the possible values quite hard to read, and they don’t really add any useful information, so I’ve taken the liberty of editing them out. I would presume that - and + do just mean ‘no’ and ‘yes’ (and 0 or N probably ‘neutral’ or ‘not applicable’?), and the pipes presumably indicate multi-part values – but I’m not sure either what exactly the ones where it seems like you can choose between the same value are supposed to be (what is -|- if not ‘no or no’?).
